# how to set concrete working directory in multi module sbt project

Tags: scala, file, module, sbt

I have package structure similar to below;

```
myapplication/
├── my-library/
│   └── src
│       └──main
│          └── scala
│   
├── my-other-library/
│   └── src/
│       └──main/
│          └── scala/
│── my-executable-project/
│   │── src/
│   │   └──main/
│   │      └── scala/
│   └── resources/
│       └── somefile.txt
└── build.sbt
```

When I run the tests via `sbt` or intellij;

- relative files (e.g. `new File("build.sbt")`) being relative to `myapplication`.

When I run the project with `reStart` via sbt-revolver or from the binary;

- `my-executable-project` is being the working directory. So to access same `build.sbt` file I should be using `new File("../build.sbt")`

---

This project structure make sense to me because there may be other executable projects later. I prefer keeping every project under the parent one.

Only `my-executable-project` is being packaged and run in the production. And when it runs there again `my-executable-project` is being the working directory.

The only inconvenience right now is when I want to reference to a relative file it is different in tests and regular runs.

I overcome resource loading with the usage of classpath and classloader but couldn't find a way for relative file references. When app runs tests fail, when tests run app fails.

---

Edit: This is how my one and only build.sbt looks like;

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)
  .aggregate(library1, library2, service, common)
  .settings(
    settings,
    name := "parent",
    version := "0.1"
  )

lazy val common = project
  .in(file("common"))
  .disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)
  .settings(
    settings,
    name := "common",
    libraryDependencies ++= ... some deps ...
  )

lazy val library1 = project
  .in(file("library1"))
  .disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    settings,
    name := "library1",
    libraryDependencies ++= ... some deps ...
  )

lazy val library2 = project
  .in(file("library2"))
  .disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    settings,
    name := "library2",
    libraryDependencies ++= ... some deps ...
  )

lazy val service = project
  .in(file("service1"))
  .dependsOn(library1, library2)
  .enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    settings,
    name := "service1",
    mappings in Universal ++= directory("service1/src/main/resources"),
    mainClass in Compile := Some("my.main.class.service.Main"),
    Revolver.enableDebugging(port = 5005, suspend = false),
    libraryDependencies ++= ... some deps ...
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved these issues putting all `sbt` stuff in the parent project.

See here the docu: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html

The main structure of `build.sbt` looks then:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(util, core)

lazy val util = (project in file("util"))

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

Every project can then be configured like:

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(generalConf.noPublishSettings)
  .settings(generalConf.buildInfoSettings)
  .settings(coreConf.settings)
```

Here you see that we use general configs `generalConf` and special project config (`coreConf`). These files are then in the `/project` folder.

Comment: I used that method as well. It solves the relative path issue, they stay same. But what happens when there are 2 executable projects, (lets say you went microservices) and their resources, their logical package hierarchy are completely different? In that case one needs to merge the resources into the parent directory since it is being the entry point to the application

Comment: If I understand you correctly all you need to do is to compose the `routes` files. Here an answer I gave this week: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56269796/2750966

Comment: no no it is unrelated to play, neither routes. It maintains a small data files in directories, credential repos, sqlite databases and those accesses are sometimes absolute sometimes relative. Relative accesses create nuances in intellij runs, revolver runs, test runs and prod runs

Comment: with relative files we only have the problem in intellij that when we run a test from a sub-project, that we have to adjust the _Working Directory_ in the config with sub-project folder, e.g. `/Users/../your-project` we have to change to `/Users/../your-project/server`