# Using the version SettingKey as a dependency version in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project

## Current situation

My project setup looks somewhat like this:

Project: **root** (`build.sbt`, `version.sbt`)
Sub-project: **projectA** (`build.sbt`)
Sub-project: **projectB** (`build.sbt`)

In my `version.sbt` I have a `val` that reads the version to use from an external json file like this:

```
version in ThisBuild := findVersion

lazy val findVersion: String =
  parse(Source.fromFile("../buildProperties.json").mkString).map(_ \\ "version").map(_ map (_.asString)) match {
    case Right(Some(x) :: _) => x
    case _     => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to read buildProperties.json")
  }
```

## The problem

I now need to use this version to define dependencies inside the subprojects (projectA & projectB). 
So I either:

1. need to access the `val findVersion` of the root project from within
   the `build.sbt` of projectA & projectB **OR**
2. need to use the version directly like this in the build.sbt of projectA & projectB: `libraryDependencies += "ext-lib" % "com.fbaierl" % version.value % Provided`. But this results in a `error: 'value' can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.` exception.

Is there any way I can achieve what I need?

Comment: Put `version.sbt` in `project` directory?

Comment: But then I need to copy it for every single sub-project, right?

Comment: you are maybe right. I usually handle multi-projects as recommendet in the Play docs. - check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286492/2750966

Comment: That would be a possibility, but I would prefer not to define all dependencies of the sub-projects in the root project as that way I feel like I'd lose a lot of the modularity I get with multi-project solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way of depending between projects would be in your root / build.sbt have something like this

```
val projectA = project in file("projectA")

val projectB = (project in file("projectB")).dependsOn(projectA)
```

If that is not what you have / need, then you can use the version task to set versions in setting dependecies like so:

```
libraryDependencies := { libraryDependencies.value :+ ("ext-lib" %% "com.fbaierl" % version.value) }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't quite understand why it works using the `libraryDependencies := ` approach, but it does! Thanks a lot.